# ModRewrite change in URL structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, gambio

I am running a webshop and recently changed my system from xtcommerce to gambio. As gambio is a fork of xtc, I thought URL handling would be the same but it seems like they handle things a little different.

My old URLs are like:
http://www.example.com/de/products/product.html
and the new ones are:
http://www.example.com/product.html

So there are plenty of 404s now and they hurt my ranking alot. 
Can someone help me to write a proper redirect, which maps the old URLs to the new one via 301 redirect ?

This is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule   ^/products/de/(.+) /$1  [R,L] 
### This should do what I want but it doesn't ...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.(php|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/admin/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/images/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/templates/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]




##boosted CONTENT
RewriteRule (.*/)?info/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html.* shop_content.php?gm_boosted_content=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]

##boosted PRODUCTS
RewriteRule (.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html product_info.php?gm_boosted_product=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]

##boosted CATEGORIES
RewriteRule (.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?.* index.php?gm_boosted_category=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your first rule isn't working.  Maybe this would work instead:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/products/de/(.+) /$1
```

or even just

```
Redirect permanent /products/de/ /
```